# Rx-java and RxJs - an existing application with open source code

Tags: rx-java, rxjs

I have been long trying to learn this RX thing, I scanned through plethora of tutorials and blogs. Now I am searching for an existing application in RxJava just to grasp more about this library.
Does anyone has an existing application in Rxjava or RxJs ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Android app, that uses rx with Retrofit : https://github.com/LiveTyping/u2020-mvp

Comment: thanks for the link :-)